# Open a new view with NavigationView (android)

Tags: android

I'm a beginner about Android world. I created my first project for testing, I use AndroidStudio and while I was creating the project I decided to select and use "Navigation Drawer Activity". 
By default Android Studio creates the `RelativeLayout` called `content_main`, so when the project starts it appears in as the first view. 
This is how the application looks like now:
[image]

and this is the `NavigationView`
[image]

This is how my project looks like:

[image]

And this is the method to switch from one view to the other:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    drawer.closeDrawers();

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_main:
            setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_stickers:
            setContentView(R.layout.content_stickers);
            return true;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
    }

}
```

I would like that when the user click on MainView button in the NavigationView will appear the MainView (content_main) and if the user click on StickersView will appear the StickerView. I really don't know how to do it, I searched on the net but nothing helped me, I hope someone will help me and let me understand this easy thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your switch you can use the FragmentManager to change the views. For each view you should have a fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment).commit();
```

Comment: So I should create a `class` that extends `Fragment` for the StickersView ?

Comment: Yes. For every view you should create a fragment.